# DropDownList only accessible in IE

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

[This page](http://bullynet.com/selectastud.aspx?id=61388) works in IE.  In Chrome and Firefox, however, the drop down at the top is not accessible.

Comment: only if we had x-ray vision to see the code

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code for your webpage here?  What specifically do you mean by "inaccessible"?  Also, have you tried anything to fix whatever the problem is yet (things that didn't work, even)?  PS: You can use the [edit] link right below your post to add the code.

Comment: [Please don't just throw a link up and say "it doesn't work."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/131713) Tell us what you've already figured out. Have you isolated the problem to any particular area of the code?

Comment: Ihor found the issue within minutes of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've glanced using developer toolbar.

The div with id="menuWrapper". It has height equal to 85px and covers dropdownlist.
Remove this style and make appropriate corrections.

Answer (score 0):

the `#topWrapper` div element has a `z-index` of 10 and a width of `990px`; which makes it overlap the drop down list impossible to click on it.

You need to come up with a better way to lay out your screen.